# Qt5 - C++ - QImage - NOT scaling right

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, scaling, qimage

I'm getting confused by the way of drawImage and scaledToHeight (or any kind of scaling) is working. Could any of you help me to understand what's going on here?

So I have the fallowing code:

```
auto cellX = this->parentWidget()->width() / 100;
auto cellY = this->parentWidget()->height() / 100;

QImage icon(dir.absoluteFilePath(m_viewModel.icon));
QImage scaled = icon.scaledToHeight(cellY * 40, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
painter.drawImage(cellX * 20, cellY * 20, scaled);
```

Now if I understand it correctly this should work as the following:

> QImage QImage::**scaledToHeight**(int height, Qt::TransformationMode mode
> = Qt::FastTransformation) const
>
> Returns a scaled copy of the image. The returned image is scaled to
> the given height using the specified transformation mode.
>
> This function automatically calculates the width of the image so that
> the ratio of the image is preserved.
>
> If the given height is 0 or negative, a null image is returned.

and also

> void QPainter::**drawImage**(int x, int y, const QImage &image, int sx =
> 0, int sy = 0, int sw = -1, int sh = -1, Qt::ImageConversionFlags
> flags = Qt::AutoColor)
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Draws an image at (x, y) by copying a part of image into the paint
> device.
>
> (x, y) specifies the top-left point in the paint device that is to be
> drawn onto. (sx, sy) specifies the top-left point in image that is to
> be drawn. The default is (0, 0).
>
> (sw, sh) specifies the size of the image that is to be drawn. The
> default, (0, 0) (and negative) means all the way to the bottom-right
> of the image.

So in other words, `scaledToHeight` is going to return a new image scaled according to that specific height and `drawImage` is going to draw that specific image started from point X, Y which I'm going to mention down to the end of the image (because it's -1 and -1 default)

[image]
[image]
[image]

**QUESTION:**

As you could see already my scaled image is strictly dependent on the position of **drawImage**, why is that? How can I scale and draw my image properly? Or in other words **WHY** if I will position my image at 0 0 or not will affect how my image looks like?

**UPDATE:**

I have my Widget Class which looks something like this:

```
class AC_SpeedLevelController : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;

private:
    AC_ButtonViewModel m_viewModel{};
public:
    explicit AC_SpeedLevelController(QWidget *parent);

    void setupStyle(const AC_ButtonViewModel &model) override;

};
```

My **paintEvent** is going to look like:

```
void AC_SpeedLevelController::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(this);

    QDir dir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
    dir.cd("icons");
    auto cellX = this->parentWidget()->width() / 100;
    auto cellY = this->parentWidget()->height() / 100;

    QImage icon(dir.absoluteFilePath(m_viewModel.icon));
    QImage scaled = icon.scaledToHeight(cellY * 20, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, scaled);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem..

Comment: the minimal use for repruduction problem is right there on my code... you just need those 5 lines of code...

Comment: The code shown is *not* complete.  What are you drawing on?  How do you set up the `QPainter` etc.?

Comment: I've just edited my question, let me know if it's ok now.

Comment: QPainter is not scaling images, unless QPainter:scale() is called. Check your widget's initPainter() methods.
The image size is not affected by the painted position !!! Verify values in parentWidget()->height(). According to your code, only parentWidget()->width()  is the variable which can change the size of your image. Take care, that the size of the widget is set when the widget is about to show. Also scaleToHeight() keeps the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: @smacker , could you give me a code example? Because now I'm more confused than before. I've check initPainter() but the thing is I'm not sure what should I do with it, and also I've tried to used `painter.scale()` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: It seems to me that `QPainter` is cropping your image. What are the dimensions of your `AC_SpeedLevelController` widget (or `QPaintEvent::rect`)? What is the value of `cellY`?

Comment: the size of `QPaintEvent::rect` will be `100x30` and the cellY is going to be **1** because the heigh of my parent is **136**. But if it's so, how can I make that QPainter is not going to crop my image?